# Calculate Phase margin of open loop system

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, linear-control

I have this system: $$\frac{(s+2)^2}{s(s-4)^2}$$
To calculate phase and magnitude margins, I used the **margins** function on matlab, and it says that the phase margin is 112º. When evaluating the phase of the transfer function on the crossover frequency, I get -428º.
The only way I found to get the same result as matlab, is to add 360º ass well as the 180º that you normally add to get the phase margin.

- When is it ok to add those 360º?
- Why does matlab not add 360º when tracing the phase bode plot?(plot goes from -450º to -90º
- Is this  in any way related to minimun phase systems?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add or subtract a multiple of 360°. I think it is easier to see why when drawing the [Nyquist diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_plot).

However in this case the closed-loop will not be stable because the open-loop is unstable (two poles at $s = 4$) and there are no [encirclements of the minus one point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_stability_criterion) in the Nyquist diagram. Since one normally only talks about margins when the system is stable, you could say that this system has no margins.